# Deallocate a bidimensional array in C

Tags: c

I have problem in C from an old college test, in which i need to deallocate a bi-dimensional array named `mat`, how do I do that or which is the correct answer?

I thought about the `a` being the good one but it says it isn't.

> Se considerà un tablou bi-dimensional alocat utilizând urmãtoarea secventã de cod:
>
> ```c
> double ** mat = 0;
> mat = ( double** ) malloc( n * sizeof( double* ) );
> if (0 == mat) {
>        fprintf( stderr, "Eroare de alocare\n" );
>        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
> }
>
> *mat = ( double* ) malloc( n * n * sizeof( double ) );
> if ( *mat == 0 ) {
>        fprintf( stderr, "Eroare de alocare\n" );
>        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
> }
> for( i=1; i<n; ++i) {
>        *( mat + i ) = *mat + i * n;
> }
> ```
>
> Care dintre variantele de mai jos poate fi utilizata pentru a dealoca acest bloc de memorie in mod corect?
>
> - a:
>
>   ```c
>   for( i=0; i<n; ++i ) {
>           free( *( mat + i ) );
>           *( mat + i ) = 0;
>   }
>   free( mat );
>   mat = 0;
>   ```
> - b:
>
>   ```c
>   free( *mat );
>   *mat = 0;
>   for( i = 1; i<n; ++i ) {
>           free( *( mat + i ) );
>            *( mat + i ) = 0;
>   }
>   free( mat );
>   mat = 0;
>   ```
> - c:
>
>   ```c
>   free( *mat );
>   *mat = 0;
>   free( mat );
>   mat = 0;
>   ```
> - d:
>
>   ```c
>   free( mat );
>   mat = 0;
>   ```

Comment: You should copy this text in as text, so people can easily copy/paste relevant portions in their answers.

Comment: Here's a hint:  The number of calls to `free` must match the number of calls to `malloc`, since each call to `free` must have a corresponding call to `malloc` (in this example, there are no `realloc` etc. calls, which makes it simple).  You can immediately identify the correct answer from that alone.

Comment: @xTitan `mat` is not a bidimensional array nor is it a pointer to one.  `mat` is a _pointer_ and it points to an (over) allocated single dimension array of pointers.

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: If we consider that it is stupid to write in a data that we destroy the line after, the cases a b c are stupid. But the least bad solution is certainly not d.

Answer (score 4):

This question is structured in a way that's trying to get you to think about the *ownership* and *lifetime* of values, beyond just merely recognizing *types* and making conclusions about memory management based off that.

You might think:

> Oh I see a `double**` or a `double[][]`, that's a 2D matrix-like array-of-arrays.. I can free the whole thing by freeing each subarray, then freeing the parent array!

But actually, that's not something you can conclude from just looking at the types alone.

If you look closely, you'll see they allocate the "parent" array (`m`) with room for `n` "subarrays", and then they allocate *only one* subarray (`*m`) with room for `n * n` doubles. Every slot of the parent array points to this one subarray at various points along its length. They all share it. Here's what a visualization (where `rows` is called `m` in your example, and `elements` is `*m`):

[image]

If you were to loop over and free each slot of the parent array separately:

1. The first `free` would be correct.
2. The second `free` would be a double-free bug, because the memory pointed to by the second slot of `mat` is the same memory just freed in the previous step.
3. Every subsequent free is a bug, for the same reason.

The correct answer would be to free the buffer that stores all the subarrays (`*m`), and then free `m` itself. This is answer C.

---

As for *why* this matrix was implemented this way:

It's a performance optimization which has several advantages:

1. It needs fewer call to `malloc()` (always just 2, instead of 1 per row needed, plus 1), which can be expensive, depending on the allocator.
2. It needs fewer allocations. Typically a memory allocator has a little bit of bookkeeping overhead for each allocation, so it can be advantageous to group many small allocations into one larger one, when possible.
3. It guarantees that the subarrays are contiguous in memory, which can improve CPU cache efficacy, thus performance.
4. It needs fewer `free()`, which can be expensive, depending on the allocator.

Here's a pretty good article I found that explains it in more detail: https://dev.to/pauljlucas/dynamically-allocating-2d-arrays-efficiently-and-correctly-in-c-23d0

Comment: It is worth noting that in any C implementation that supports variably-modified types (but not necessarily automatically allocated objects of such types), all of the advantages you present are better achieved, without any change of access syntax, by allocating a *bona fide* 2D array dynamically: `double (*mat)[n] = malloc(n * sizeof(*mat));`.  That yields only a single call each to `malloc` and `free`, for a single allocation, and contiguity of the entire array of arrays. All *conforming* C99 and (soon) C23 implementations support this.  Most C11 and C17 implementations do, too.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Neat, thanks for sharing! I had done something similar in the past, where I used only a single `malloc((n*sizeof(double *) + n*n*sizeof(double *))`, in which I put the `rows` array at the start, followed by the `elements` array after. I still needed to loop over the `rows` slots and wire up the pointers into the `elements` region correctly though, which was fiddly. I also got it super wrong on my first attempt, and spent so long debugging that I remember this story to this day :')